# Email Validation in a controller Grails

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, sendmail, email-validation

I'm just trying to validate an email address in a Controller which I thought would be simple. The method I've done is as follows:

```
def emailValidCheck(String emailAddress)  {
    EmailValidator emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance()
    if (!emailAddress.isAllWhitespace() || emailAddress!=null) {
        String[] email = emailAddress.replaceAll("//s+","").split(",")
        email.each {
            if (emailValidator.isValid(it)) {
            return true
            }else {return false}
        }
    }
}
```

This is being used with a sendMail function, which my code for that is here:

```
def emailTheAttendees(String email) {
    def user = lookupPerson()
    if (!email.isEmpty()) {
        def splitEmails = email.replaceAll("//s+","").split(",")
        splitEmails.each {
            def String currentEmail = it
            sendMail {
                to currentEmail
                System.out.println("what's in to address:"+ currentEmail)
                subject "Your Friend ${user.username} has invited you as a task attendee"
                html g.render(template:"/emails/Attendees")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works and sends emails to valid email addresses, but if I put in something random that is not an address just breaks with sendMail exception. I can't understand why it's not validating correctly and even going into the emailTheAttendees() method ... which is being called in the save method.

Comment: I saw an email regex once. It was like 4 pages long.

Comment: The return in your email.each closure only returns from current iteration of the closure.

Comment: @JamesKleeh - And that likely only covered the _common_ cases!

Comment: new user tip: you should add programming language tag to you question.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses !

@wwwclaes OK thank you for that, I'm still learning...

In the 'emailValidCheck' function, the if that's evaluating the email is only being ran the once e.g. 'if (emailValidator.isValid(it))' ? So are you saying that some form of counter is needed to make sure each  one has been checked ? Thanks

Comment: [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) is a nice roundup about regex and emails. Good to get a feeling about the difficulties and a fair trade-off between complexity and usability. in your special case, Nicholas (accepted) answer should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [constraints](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/validation.html) and [a command object](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects) to achieve this. Example:

Command Object:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class YourCommand {
    String email
    String otherStuffYouWantToValidate

    static constraints = {
        email(blank: false, email: true)
        ...
    }
}
```

Call it like this in your controller:

```
class YourController {
    def yourAction(YourCommand command) {
        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            // handle errors
            return
        }

        // work with the command object data
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with email:true is that it doesn't recognize the many new tlds.

Comment: That should be addressed in Grails then. Have you filed a bug with them? If I remember correctly, Grails is using apache commons for the email validation, so an upgrade should suffice.