# Grails development process

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am pretty new to grails. In the past I have created web applications with `jsf 2.0`. Usually I created every class by "hand". Therefore scaffolding of grails comes extremely handy to me.

So my question is:
Do you just create the domain layer and then just modify the scafolded views?
Whats your typical development process in `grails 2.3.4`?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development process depends on your type of project and experience.

- I personally create lots of crud applications with the same corporate identity. So I use the scaffolding as you described: create views and controllers, then modify them. In order to apply the corporate identity, I've modified the default stylesheet and apply it through a self made plugin.
- If you create crud like applications, but the scaffolding doesn't fit, you can do a `install-templates` and modify the resulting scaffolding templates. This way, you can easily modify the structure of your scaffolded pages (for instance add an Excel-Export for all list pages as default)
- In other projects, my main pages are not crud like, so I manually create them. But I still need a lot of admin pages which are crud like - these I still scaffold and even don't have to modify. That spares a lot of effort
- If scaffolded pages do not fit and you are experienced enough in Grails, @moeTi is right that manually coding your controllers and views might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

For now until your more familiar its a great starting point to generate contollers and views. I think you will need to get more specific as to what it is you want to do with your controller views outside of scaffolding.

[Email Validation in a controller Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481619/email-validation-in-a-controller-grails)

Take look here for an example of a validation class that you could makeup and add at a bottom of a controller. This then gives you the power to custom verify. Hand made forms

Take a look at spring security plugin and if needed restrict delete edit to certain group of users.

In a lot of my earlier controllers I did a basic generation and then ended adding extra functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't really like the scaffolded views, although you can modify the templates. It's a good way to get started quickly, but you will soon realize that it's a lot of work to modify them to your needs.

You can scaffold and modify until you understand the GSP underpinnings, but at some point you will realize that you could write the whole thing faster than create and modify everything. And you can outsource code into templates and/or taglibs.

On the other hand, if you really just need default layout CRUD operation UI for your database, scaffolded views are probably good enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start and brief info about scaffolding

Scaffolding lets you generate some basic CRUD interfaces for a domain class, including:
The necessary views and Controller actions for create/read/update/delete (CRUD) operations.

static scaffold = true // by setting scaffold to true

With this configured, when you start your application the actions and views will be auto-generated at runtime. The following actions are dynamically implemented by default by the runtime scaffolding mechanism:

```
a)index  b)show c)edit d)delete e)create f)save g)update
```

then you could customize the generated views of your need.

I am sure the default views never fit to your need, so i would always go with my own view from the beginning.

But Yes!, if you are a beginner and want grails to help you how the controller and view looks like you can always start with it and feel the ease of grails framework

Thanks
Motilal